# "GROUP_CONCAT()" Multiple columns through foreign key

Tags: sqlite

I have the following tables

Book table

```
id     title       authors
3      Linux
```

authors table

```
id   firstname  lastname   fk
1      name       name     3
2      name2      name     3
```

I would like to query authors table to get authors column filled something like this table using GROUP_CONCAT()

```
id   title            authors
3    Linux    name name | name2 name2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a single book whose ID you know, you can get the list of authors as a single value like this:

```
SELECT group_concat(firstname || ' ' || lastname)
FROM authors
WHERE fk = ?;
```

Just use this as a [correlated subquery](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#cosub) in the actual query:

```
SELECT id,
       title,
       (SELECT group_concat(firstname || ' ' || lastname, ' | ')
        FROM authors
        WHERE fk = book.id
       ) AS authors
FROM book;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that was helpful